# Replacement for gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

There are a couple of questions like this, but I still haven't really understood. I was coding with OpenGL over 10 years ago and noticed how difficult it is to get into modern OpenGL. The OpenGL.org page is a horrible mess when it comes to examples, you never know what version it is, any version seems to be mixed up in various code examples.
Alright, I have an old code I want to update to OpenGL >3 at least. So first thing I did was to move on from glVertex3fv to finally make it with glVertexAttribPointer (over a step with glVertexPointer until I read this is deprecated now as well). This works out fine, but when trying to place textures I got stuck quickly and I assume it is because of wrong positioning and I wanted to get rid of c++ code :

```
glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
glLoadIdentity();
glFrustum( -RProjZ, +RProjZ, -Aspect*RProjZ, +Aspect*RProjZ, 1.0, 32768.0 );
```

and to draw it

```
// bind vertex buffer
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * size, verts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// enable arrays
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0); 

// set pointers
glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * floatsPerVertex, 0);

// render ComplexSurface
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, size);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

with in the vertexshader

```
gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
```

And everything is working magically. Now don't get me wrong, I'm a big fan of magic, but...
Then I found a couple of matrix conversions which can be used to get a matrix to replace glFrustum, but whenever I try to replace it, it fails badly (although I think I understood the maths behind glFrustum and the conversion into the matrix).

What tried is something like

```
buildPerspProjMat(g_ProjView,FovAngle,Aspect,1.0,32768.0 );

glUseProgram(g_program);
glUniformMatrix4fv(g_programFrustum, 1, GL_FALSE, g_ProjView );
glUseProgram(0);
```

and using the position in the shader from the buffer above with the projection matix, but this doesn't work out at all.

So what I plain don't get now is where to replace this and with what in the shader. I don't know at which point the glMatrixMode takes place and "when" to replace it with some uniform matrix (passing the args as uniform ain't the problem here).
I can't count how many tutorials I read already, but I always get confused over all the mixed versions. I am always happy about some code examples, but please OpenGL 3 or higher.

The next would be a replacement for glTexCoord2f for texturing, but that's a different story :)

Comment: Now there was another comment on this with quite some information but was deleted a few minutes ago and a -1 put instead, but I didn't find the time to copy out the links and read all the information yet. I added some more information into my original question and it's sad it got removed, because I don't think it was not fitting to my question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I find that when thinking about modern OpenGL it is best to forget that `glMatrixMode` ever existed.

With that in mind, let's go over what you need for the most basic draw operation: a replacement for `gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix`. As it's name implies this is a combination of 3 different matrices: the model matrix, the view matrix, and the projection matrix.

So what you'll need in your shader to accomodate this is 3 uniform variables of type `mat4`. Which you'll use like so:

```
uniform mat4 projMat;
uniform mat4 viewMat;
uniform mat4 modelMat;

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projMat * viewMat * modelMat * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

This bit of shader code performs the same function as the one you had above. What changed is the built-in `gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix` was replaced by 3 uniform variables (which could be combined as one if you make sure to multiply them yourself on the C++ side before passing it in). And the builtin `gl_Vertex` was replaced by an input variable.

On the C++ side you will need to do 2 things. First you'll need to get the location for each of these uniforms:

```
GLuint modelMatIdx = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgId, "modelMat");
GLuint viewMatIdx = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgId, "viewMat");
GLuint projMatIdx = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgId, "projMat");
```

And with this in hand you can now pass in the values for each uniform right before drawing using `glUniformMatrix4fv`.

One particular library which makes this particularly easy is [glm](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.5/index.html). For example to get the same projection matrix as in your example you would do:

```
glm::mat4 projMat = glm::frustum(-RProjZ, +RProjZ, -Aspect*RProjZ, +Aspect*RProjZ, 1.0, 32768.0);
```

and you would pass it in like so:

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(projMatIdx, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projMat));
```

Now that you know how, I'd like to address the issue of "when". You said you weren't clear about the matrix mode stuff and that brings me back to my earlier assertion of "forget about it". The matrix mode was there so that you could tell opengl which built in should be affected by calls to OpenGL matrix operations such as glTranslate, glFrustum and so on, but all of this is gone now. You are now in charge of managing the (possibly many) matrices involved. All you have to do is pass them in before you draw (as I've shown above) and you'll be fine. Just make sure the program is bound before you attempt to modify its uniforms.

Here's a working example (if you're suprised by gl::... instead of gl... it's because I'm using an opengl header generated by glLoadGen which puts all of the opengl API functions in the gl namespace).

```
GLuint simpleProgramID;
// load the shader and make the program

GLuint modelMatIdx = gl::GetUniformLocation(simpleProgramID, "modelMat");
GLuint viewMatIdx = gl::GetUniformLocation(simpleProgramID, "viewMat");
GLuint projMatIdx = gl::GetUniformLocation(simpleProgramID, "projMat");

GLuint vaoID;
gl::GenVertexArrays(1, &vaoID);
gl::BindVertexArray(vaoID);

GLuint vertBufferID, indexBufferID;
gl::GenBuffers(1, &vertBufferID);
gl::GenBuffers(1, &indexBufferID);

struct Vec2 { float x, y; };
struct Vec3 { float x, y, z; };
struct Vert { Vec3 pos; Vec2 tex; };

std::array<Vert, 8> cubeVerts = {{
    { {  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f }, { 1.0f, 0.0f } }, { {  0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f } },
    { {  0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f }, { 0.0f, 1.0f } }, { {  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f }, { 0.0f, 0.0f } },
    { { -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f }, { 0.0f, 0.0f } }, { { -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f }, { 0.0f, 1.0f } },
    { { -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f } }, { { -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f }, { 1.0f, 0.0f } }
}};

std::array<unsigned int, 36> cubeIdxs = {{ 
    0, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2, // Right
    4, 5, 6, 4, 6, 7, // Left
    0, 7, 3, 0, 4, 7, // Top
    1, 6, 2, 1, 5, 6, // Bottom
    0, 5, 1, 0, 4, 5, // Front
    3, 7, 6, 3, 6, 2  // Back
}};

// Vertex buffer
gl::BindBuffer(gl::ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBufferID);
gl::BufferData(gl::ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vert) * cubeVerts.size(), cubeVerts.data(), gl::STATIC_DRAW);
gl::EnableVertexAttribArray(0); // Matches layout (location = 0)
gl::VertexAttribPointer(0, 3, gl::FLOAT, gl::FALSE_, sizeof(Vert), 0);
gl::EnableVertexAttribArray(1); // Matches layout (location = 1)
gl::VertexAttribPointer(1, 2, gl::FLOAT, gl::FALSE_, sizeof(Vert), (GLvoid*)sizeof(Vec3));

// Index buffer
gl::BindBuffer(gl::ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBufferID);
gl::BufferData(gl::ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned int) * cubeIdxs.size(), cubeIdxs.data(), gl::STATIC_DRAW);
gl::BindVertexArray(0);

glm::mat4 projMat = glm::perspective(56.25f, 16.0f/9.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
glm::mat4 viewMat = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(5, 5, 5), glm::vec3(0, 0, 0), glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));
glm::mat4 modelMat; // identity

while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    gl::Clear(gl::COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl::DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl::UseProgram(simpleProgramID);
    gl::UniformMatrix4fv(projMatIdx, 1, gl::FALSE_, glm::value_ptr(projMat));
    gl::UniformMatrix4fv(viewMatIdx, 1, gl::FALSE_, glm::value_ptr(viewMat));
    gl::UniformMatrix4fv(modelMatIdx, 1, gl::FALSE_, glm::value_ptr(modelMat));

    gl::BindVertexArray(vaoID);
    gl::DrawElements(gl::TRIANGLES, 36, gl::UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    gl::BindVertexArray(0);

    gl::UseProgram(0);

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

Associated Vertex Shader:

```
//[VERTEX SHADER]
#version 430

uniform mat4 projMat;
uniform mat4 viewMat;
uniform mat4 modelMat;

layout (location = 0) in vec3 in_position; // matches gl::EnableVertexAttribArray(0);
layout (location = 1) in vec2 in_uv; // matches gl::EnableVertexAttribArray(1);

out vec2 uv;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projMat * viewMat * modelMat * vec4(in_position, 1.0);
    uv = in_uv;
}
```

And finally Fragment shader:

```
//[FRAGMENT SHADER]
#version 430

in vec2 uv;

out vec4 color;

void main()
{
    color = vec4(uv, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

The resulting image is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks,this answered quite a lot of things already. What I am now unsure about in your example is:
glm::mat4 modelMat; // identity - also I read in a few tutorials already about GLM and I used it in some easy testing programs, but it felt for me in the first place to change one magic which works against another magic which didn't (in my attempt to get rid of gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix at least), so I wanted to avoid using it at first. I think now I understand why it didn't work though.

Comment: THANK YOU FOR THIS! I have spent way too many hours trying to figure all of this stuff out. I didn't realize just how much of the OpenGL I used to be familiar with has been deprecated. I have been getting very frustrated trying to figure out how to replace all of the deprecated stuff.

By the way, the image I get is upside down compared to yours... any idea why that might be?

Comment: OpenGL has a nasty habit of deprecating perfectly good features without providing any replacement other than "do it yourself". Like, yeah, I'm fine with doing it myself if I need to do something that the premade functions can't do, but if the premade functions are already there, and often useful, what's the problem with keeping them around for convenience and backward-compatibility?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I agree that most OpenGL tutorials confuse bits of deprecated and non-deprecated stuff. To get you in the right direction, let me explain.

`gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix`, `gl_ModeView`, `glMatrixMode()` and the matrix stack `glPushMatrix()` `glPopMatrix()` are deprecated. You need to define your own matrices as a uniform variables then set and pass them to the shader using `glUniform*`.

`gl_Vertex` is also deprecated, actually the whole fixed attributes names are deprecated. Alternatively you need to define your own attribute names and bind them to specific locations. Then you can set their values using `glVertexAttribPointer` by passing the attribute location to it ([Full explanation here](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Basics/Tut02%20Vertex%20Attributes.html#d0e2471)). For example:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices); // for vertices
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, color); // for color
```

And for the shader code

```
layout (location = 0) in vec4 vertex;
layout (location = 1) in vec4 color;

uniform mat4 modelview;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
gl_Position = projection* modelview* vertex;
}
```

For the attributes locations you can set them in the shader code as I did, or from OpenGL API using [glBindAttribLocation](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBindAttribLocation.xml).

Managing uniform variables can be somehow tricky if you are used to the old OpenGL globals variables such as `gl_ModelView` I wrote an [article](http://codingshuttle.com/2013/05/a-generic-solution-for-handling-opengl-3-1-uniform-variables/) that hopefully can help you manage uniform variables for a big project.

Comment: it's always good to have a different views on the same topic, especially when it comes to understanding, also I think your article could be very useful for me later. Great you added it back.

Comment: Argh!  What is wrong with the Khronos folks?  Again and again they show that they do not understand the meaning of "deprecate."  It's supposed to be *something you do when you have a better replacement for the functionality in question,* but they repeatedly use it to make things *worse* on us instead, taking things that used to "just work" and dumping it in our laps to re-implement manually, if that's even possible.  (I still haven't seen a good replacement for `GL_QUADS`, for example!)

Comment: @MasonWheeler GL_QUADS are deprecated because TRIANGLES are faster for the GPU to draw, what I usually do is build a quad abstraction over two triangles, and when I pass the data structure to OpenGL to draw I pass them as triangles. Yeah, I guess that what you meant by re-implement manually.

Comment: @concept3d: The problem with doing it as TRIANGLES is that you need to pass six vertices to draw an object with four.  If you're drawing thousands or tens of thousands of quads (quite possible in a 2D game with a tile map) that can become a big difference pretty quickly!  If it's faster for the GPU to draw triangles than quads, that means someone screwed up in writing the GPU driver; it should be exactly as fast because it takes care of it under the hood in an optimal fashion, without dumping all that work into the developer's lap.

Comment: @MasonWheeler Well I am not particularly sure that someone screwed writing the driver, what I know is that GPU needed to triangulate quads under the hood because triangle rasterization is much faster than quad rasterization. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9511/why-do-game-engines-convert-models-to-triangles-compared-to-keeping-it-as-four-s also my answer here http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/66312/quads-vs-triangles/66314#66314

Comment: @concept3d That's the point, though: triangle rasterization shouldn't be any faster than quad rasterization, because a quad can be trivially converted into triangles by the GPU by simply drawing a line between two opposite vertices.  (Especially in the most common case for quads, 2D graphics, in which all 4 vertices are coplanar.)  Throughout the entire history of computer programming, progress has come by improving frameworks allowing developers to work at a higher level of abstraction.  The OpenGL folks seem to not understand this, though, since they keep doing exactly the opposite.