# Augmented Reality - Rendering 3D objects using projection matrix

Tags: opengl, computer-vision, openscenegraph

I have a calibration method that extracts from a static scene the projection matrix
P = K[R | t] of the scene (where Z is the height and Z=0 is the ground plane).

My question is what the easiest way to plot a 3D object in this scene using the
projection matrix P? A few years ago I made a similar code that used OSG to
plot the object (however in that case I had estimates of the intrinsic and
extrinsic parameters separately).

Do you guys know how to render the 3D in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Define "easiest"? In opengl you can just set you projection matrix as the modelview, and start drawing. Caveats, the usual ones: make sure your viewport / clipping planes make sense.

Comment: I think the problem here is that I do not have camera intrinsic parameters to put in the OpenGL camera. What I think I will do is to perform a RQ decomposition in the projection matrix and then I can estimate these parameters.

Comment: See this other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21980947/replacement-for-gl-position-gl-modelviewprojectionmatrix-gl-vertex