# OpenGL PyQt object not scaling

Tags: opengl, pyqt, glsl, shader, opengl-compat

I have just translated my old glBegin and glEnd code into one using VBOs and VAOs. As framework, I am using Pyqt. I did managed to load a 3D object and to display it on the screen, but I can not scale it. I tried after glLoadIdentity in paintGL method, but nothing changed. How could I scale it?
Here is my code:

```
vertex_code = '''
    attribute vec2 position;
    void main()
    {
        gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
        gl_Position.y -= 0.5;
    }
    '''
fragment_code = '''
    void main()
    {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.3);
    }
    '''

class ObjRender(QOpenGLWidget):
  
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QGLWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.object = ObjectLoader("myobj.obj")
        self.triangleVertices = []
        self.angle = 0
   
  
    def initializeGL(self):
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        glShadeModel(GL_FLAT)
        glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE)

        program = glCreateProgram()
        vertex = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
        fragment = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)

        glShaderSource(vertex, vertex_code)
        glShaderSource(fragment, fragment_code)
        
        glCompileShader(vertex)
        ## handle errors
        glCompileShader(fragment)
        ## handle errors 

        glAttachShader(program, vertex)
        glAttachShader(program, fragment)

        glLinkProgram(program)
        ## handle errors

        glDetachShader(program, vertex)
        glDetachShader(program, fragment)
        
        glUseProgram(program)

        ## build data
        glClearColor(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.7)
        glClearDepth(1.0)
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

        self.initializeVertices()
        self.triangleVertices = array(self.triangleVertices, 'f')

        self.vertexBufferObject = VBO(self.triangleVertices)
        self.vertexBufferObject.bind()

        self.vertexArrayObject = glGenVertexArrays(1)

        glBindVertexArray(self.vertexArrayObject)
        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 3*self.triangleVertices.itemsize, None)
        glBindVertexArray(0)

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
        glLoadIdentity()
    def paintGL(self):
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        glLoadIdentity()
        glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -10.0)
        glScalef(0.2, 0.2, 0.2)
        glBindVertexArray(self.vertexArrayObject)
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, len(self.triangleVertices))
        glBindVertexArray(0)
        glFlush()

    
    def resizeGL(self, width, height):    
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
        gluPerspective(45, 2.0, 7.0, 1000.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still want to us the [Legacy OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL) fixed function matrix stack, then you have to transform the vertex position by the `gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix` in the vertex shader:

```c
attribute vec2 position;

void main()
{
    vec4 pos = vec4(position.x, position.y-0.5, 0.0, 1.0);
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * pos; 
}
```

---

Note, the matrix stack is deprecated as long as the immediate mode (`glBegin`/`glEnd` sequences). Nowadays the vertex transformations are done by user defined matrix [Uniform](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_(GLSL)) variables. See also [GLSL Programming/Vector and Matrix Operations](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Vector_and_Matrix_Operations) and [Replacement for gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21980947/replacement-for-gl-position-gl-modelviewprojectionmatrix-gl-vertex/21982269)